# How to remove a NamedRange in Google Sheet that contains specific text using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to remove all Named Ranges that contain the text "campaigns".

I am trying the below, it's executing but not working

```
function removeNamedRanges(){
    var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges().map(x => x.getName()).filter(y => y.includes('campaigns'));


        namedRanges.forEach(range=>range.remove());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code I understand that you're creating an Array that contains the name of all the named ranges, you can use that name to delete it by calling the [`removeNamedRange(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removenamedrangename) method:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function removeNamedRanges() {
  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges().map(x => x.getName()).filter(y => y.includes('campaigns'));
  namedRanges.forEach(range => ss.removeNamedRange(range));
}
```

This only deletes the name associated to that range, you can use this modification to delete its contents:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function removeNamedRanges() {
  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges();
  for (const namedRange of namedRanges) {
    if (namedRange.getName().includes("campaigns")) {
      ss.removeNamedRange(namedRange.getName());
      var range = namedRange.getRange();
      range.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Bryan and thank you for your kind support. I ran your modified script, it  executed successfully but the named ranges containing the word "campaigns" are still there. So nothing happened.  The ranges' names are the client's name followed by the word "campaigns" with no spaces. For example, `xcampaigns`, `ycampaigns` etc...

Comment: That's odd, it works for me when testing [like this](https://imgur.com/a/mEc1zfS). Could you share a sample spreadsheet? Happy to help.

Comment: I'm preparing a sample spreadsheet right now and I'll share it in a bit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A simple refresh did the job :) I checked the sample spreadsheet before sending it over and noticed the script worked! I refreshed the initial spreadsheet and it worked there also. Thank you so much for your support Bryan! I appreciate it :)